# macOS accessibility: can't move focus to "Finder wants to make changes" password prompt/window using keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, finder

I tried Googling for a solution to this issue but can't find one. When deleting certain files/folders, Finder will pop up a window prompting me to enter my password. If another app/window steals the focus before I can enter my password, I am unable to get the focus back to the password prompt window using the keyboard.

In System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Keyboard, I have all shortcut options enabled for keyboard access and moving focus, and the button for "all controls" is selected for the "Full Keyboard Access" option.

I've tried using <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>,  <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>, and  <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>, but none of these seem to allow me to move the keyboard focus to this window.

Please help. This can be a very frustrating problem for those who have difficulty using a mouse, particularly anyone with Parkinson's or other mobility issues. Thank you.

Comment: I don't have an answer, & this is not an easy one for me to test, but did you try the regular Cmd/Tab/down arrow to see if you can get to it? [I have a feeling the dialog may be opened by a non-visible process, so it's not going to be that simple unfortunately] Alternatively, swapping to Mouse Keys [default 5 taps on Opt to toggle] to see if that would allow you sufficient control over the regular cursor?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. To test, you can try deleting an app in your Applications folder. That'll give you the password prompt. From there, you can ⌘+tab to move focus to another app. ⌘+tab+⇣ didn't help to refocus the prompt. Mouse Keys works, but is much slower than it would be to shift the focus to the floating window with a shortcut. I'm betting there's some way to do this with a script in an Automator service that I could assign a shortcut to.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the dialog is being called by an invisible process so pulling it to the front might be tough. Automator, however, can do mouse-clicks, but it's not something I've ever investigated. I found https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/358838/how-can-i-automate-mouse-clicks-and-keyboard-input-with-automator-in-mac-mojave and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24003/automator-simulation-of-the-mouse-and-keyboard which might help. Wish you luck with this :)